# Parse Cloud Code loading a to-Many relationship

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, one-to-many

I have several relationships on Parse and I am attempting to perform a query to pull back all the data.

Classes:

- Equipment
- EquipmentType
- EquipmentAttribute
- Notification
- NotificationType
- Equipment has an EquipmentType
- Equipment has many EquipmentAttributes
- Equipment has many Notifications
- Notification has a NotificationType

I would like to query for all Equipment whose EquipmentType is equalTo "robot" and have the result include all EquipmentAttributes and Notifications associated.

I have been unsuccessful in finding a way to perform this query. I have tried the following:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("getFleetList", function(request, response) {
  var typeQ = new Parse.Query("EquipmentType");
  typeQ.equalTo("code", "robot");

  var equipmentQ = new Parse.Query("Equipment");
  equipmentQ.include("type");
  equipmentQ.matchesQuery("type", typeQ);

  var attribQ = new Parse.Query("EquipmentAttribute");
  attribQ.include("equipment");
  attribQ.matchesQuery("equipment", equipmentQ);
  attribQ.find({
    success: function(results) {
      response.success(results);
    },
    error: function(error) {
      response.error("lookup failed: code:" + error.code + " message:" + error.message);
    }
  });
});
```

But this will only bring back Equipment that has EquipmentAttributes and misses all of the ones that don't.

How can I pull back all the information and return it in a single JSON response?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Unless you've created a two-way relationship between `Equipment` and `EquipmentAttribute` you'll have to do two queries and manually assemble the results.

If you had an `attributes` property on `Equipment` of type Array then you could just use `equipmentQ.include("attributes");` and not bother with the query against `EquipmentAttribute`.

If needed I can provide a sample of either solution.